# Extracting data from pandas data frame to a new data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a data structure in my code which is a dictionary of dictionaries. The nested dictionary has all the keys as pandas data frames. Basically, I had multiple excel files with multiple tabs and columns, so I created this data structure as I wanted to further do some modeling on this data. Now, I want to extract two columns from one specific tab of each excel file(if they are present in that file) and print them in a new master data frame. I tried some routines but was not able to get the expected result. Please find below the code that I tried to resolve this issue.

```
def text_extraction_to_dataframe(dict1, process_key):
    '''This routine is used to extract any required column from the data into a new dataframe with the file name as new
    column attached to it'''        
    
    #Initializing new data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['ExcelFile'] = ''
    
    #Running nested for-loops to get into our data structure(dictionary of dictionaries)
    for key, value in dict1.items():
                    
        for key1, value1 in value.items():

            #Checking if the required tab matches to the key
            if key1 == process_key:
                    
                df = pd.DataFrame(value1)   #Extracting all the data from the tab to the new dataframe

                df['ExcelFile'] = key.split('.')[0]  #Appending the data frame with new column as the filename
        
    #Removing unnecessary columns from the data frame and only keeping column3 and column4
    df = df.drop(columns = ['colum_1', 'column2']) 
    return df

text_extraction_to_dataframe(dictionary, 'tab_name')
```

This routine is not extracting all the data from all the columns of each excel file.

Also, I want to get the last column of the master data frame as the excel file name.

Basically, the structure of master df will be [column3, column4, excelfilename]

Let me know if you need anything else other than this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you overwrite `df` inside your loop, so it can only ever include the values in the last iteration. so that's probably an important issue to sort out. but maybe you could get around this by just using [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)? by default, it will return a dictionary with `{sheet_name: DataFrame}` key value pairs

Comment: I have already used pe.read_excel while extracting the data into memory. Now, all the data is there in the nested dictionary. I need to use the same structure to extract the data here. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this query by adding all the data frames into a list and then concatenating those. Please find below the code.

```
def text_extraction_to_dataframe(dictionary, process_key):
    '''This routine is used to extract any required column from the data into a 
     new data frame with the file name as a new column attached to it'''        
    
    #List to append all the read data frames
    master_df1 = []
    length = len(dictionary)
    
    #Running nested for-loops to get into our data structure(dictionary of dictionaries)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
            
        for key1, value1 in value.items():
                
            #Checking if the required tab matches to the key
            if key1 == process_key:
                df = pd.DataFrame(value1)

                #Adding the excel file name as the last column in each data frame
                df['ExcelFile'] = key.split('.')[0]
                
                #Appending all data frames in the list
                master_df1.append(df)
    
    #Concatenating all the data frames in the master data frame            
    master_df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(master_df1, ignore_index=True))
    
    #Dropping unnecessary column
    master_df1 = master_df1.drop(columns=['column1', 'column2'])
    
    return master_df1
```